# Can't destructure props in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, object-destructuring

I'm getting some trouble on destructuring props when passing an object to a child component. This object has 2 values, one is another object and the second is a function.

This is my code in case any of you can help:
Parent cmp:

```
export const AdminScreen = () => {
  const {kolorTokenContract, setContract} = useContext(ContractsContext);

  console.log("contract from admin: ", kolorTokenContract);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Administrator Screen</h1>
      <hr />

      <div className="row align-items-center">
        <ERC20AdminForm props={{kolorTokenContract, setContract}} />
        <TokenInfo {...kolorTokenContract} />
      </div>
      <hr />
      <Balance />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child cmp:

```
export const ERC20AdminForm = ({kolorTokenContract, setContract}) => {
  //console.log("props from erc20admin form: ", props);
  console.log("contract from erc20admin form: ", kolorTokenContract);

  return (
    <div className="col-8 col-md-6 col-sm-4 ">
      <MintingForm props={kolorTokenContract} />
      <SetVaultForm />
      <TransferOwnershipForm />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If i log the "kolorTokenContract" i just get undefined :(. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For Child component:

```
const ERC20AdminForm = (props:any) => {
console.log("contract from erc20admin form: ", props.kolorTokenContract);

  return (
    <div className="col-8 col-md-6 col-sm-4 ">
      <MintingForm kolorTokenContract={props.kolorTokenContract} />
      <SetVaultForm />
      <TransferOwnershipForm />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Call from a parent with separate props:

```html
<ERC20AdminForm kolorTokenContract={kolorTokenContract} setContract={setContract} />
```

This is a [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leftpad-zkkh9?file=/src/App.tsx) for proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin screen you should check for the `kolorTokenContract` . what does the context return?
from where do you get the value of `kolorTokenContract`, does it come from an api?
if it is then I am guessing while defining the state you didn't give it a value.
For solution, you can give an empty object while defining the `kolorTokenContract` in your context or you can set a default value

```
const {kolorTokenContract = {}, setContract} = useContext(ContractsContext);
```